# Best practices asp.net mvc: working with images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

what are the best practices to process images in enterptices web applications.
I mean

- storing
- assign with entity
- fast loading/caching
- delayed  / ajax loading
- suitable format (png, jpeg)
- on fly editing (resizing, compress)
- free libs/helpers
- image watermarking/copyrighting on fly
  Especially, appreciated already production approaches!

Comment: This question is too open-ended, I suggest you rephrase it and be more specific if you want to get any useful answers from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ImageMagickObject in my mvc projects. It can:

- suitable format (png, jpeg)
- on flyediting (resizing, compress)
- freelibs/helpers image
- watermarking/copyrighting on fly

fast loading/caching: may be memcached?
delayed / ajax loading: jquery is a good solution
assign with entity: Entity Framework can work with almost all databases
storing: hard question. all depend to the functionality

Comment: good link to my solution over imageMagickObject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882307/generating-image-thumbnails-in-asp-net/5884231#5884231

Answer (score 2):

As always, every project has their own requirements, restrictions and resources (The 3Rs).  There is no 'super pattern' or 'one size fits all' method.

We cannot tell you how to implement you project as every project is different. It's up to you to use your skills/knowledge and experience to make informed decisions on implementation.

The 'best practice' is to individually research and learn each of the technologies/methods you have listed and gain the knowledge to know when to use them based on your projects requirements, restrictions and resources.

Comment: OK, I mean technology best practices. It's clear that when we have 3R.But I develop my own project and actually don't know how it will be scaled in  future. Any, technology have best general approach and I interesed in tehcnology approach in particular.

Comment: Nothing in development is permanent, I would worry about scaling when you're lucky enough to have that problem. There can be recommended design patterns but they're not a 'magic bullet' for every project.  You need to understand the patterns or best practices in order to know when to use them and when not to use them.  This question is to broad to get any decent answer from it.